# How to create feed to share MY ever-changing location with users on my site

Tags: html, css, feed

Total newb here, so please forgive my ignorance. I'm creating a portfolio site as a novice, nomadic developer/designer (HTML & CSS only for now). I'd like to add a feed that will share ONLY my current city/country with visitors without having to go through the whole process of updating the site every time I travel. I don't want to share my whole Twitter or Instagram feed or anything like that.

Is there any way to embed a feed into my site that only shares my current location via Twitter/IG or something similarly easy to update?

Comment: Can you use [Filtering Tweets by location](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tutorials/filtering-tweets-by-location.html)?

Comment: Not sure... filtering seems to display Tweets from a specified location, whereas I'm trying to avoid displaying the Tweets and show only location data. But maybe there's a workaround I'm unaware of. I'll look into it! Thanks for taking the time to respond :)

Comment: So it seems that what I'm wanting to do here is not currently possible. For now I'm just embedding a Google map to my site and I'll have to update it whenever I move/travel.